# Series of holomorphic functions and residue exercise

Tags: complex-analysis

Name $f (z) $ the sum $$\sum_1^\infty f_n(z) =\sum_1^\infty 
\frac 1 {e^{nz}-1}.$$

> I have to 1) show that $f $ is holomorphic in $\Pi=\{z\in \mathbb C:\mathrm {Re} (z)\gt 0\}$; 2) calculate $$\int_{C_{\frac 1 2} (1)} \frac {f (z)}{(z-1)^2}dz$$ and $$\lim _{j\to \infty}\int_{C_{\frac 1 2} (j)} \frac {f (z)}{(z-j)^2}dz.$$

For the first point, the series converges pointwise for every $z\in \Pi $; plus, it converges uniformly in every compact subset of $\pi$. In fact, if we consider a compact set $A $ contained in $\Pi $, we have that $\mathrm {Re} (z) \ge \delta \gt 0$ for every $z\in A $: then, $\mathrm {Sup}_A |f_n (z)|=\frac 1 {e^{n\delta} -1}$, and $\sum\frac 1 {e^{n\delta} -1}\lt \infty$. By Weierstrass' theorem the convergence is uniform, and this proves that $f (z) $ is holomorphic (since every $f_n $ is holomorphic).

I don't understand if I'm missing something in the other point: calculating the first integral should consist of compute $2\pi i \sum f_n'(1)$, since the uniform convergence makes the integral and the sum commute. However the sum $$\sum_1^\infty \frac {-ne^{n}}{ (e^{n}-1)^2}$$ isn't a very nice sum (although it converges). At this point, consider $\sum \frac {-ne^{nj}}{ (e^{nj}-1)^2}$; as $j $ increase, it is asymptotic to $\sum \frac {-n}{ e^{nj}}$. This last sum is finite if $j =1$, call its value $\alpha $; for every natural $k $, we can find a $j_0$ such that $\sum \frac {-n}{ e^{nj_0}} \le \frac \alpha k$. This means that the limit requested is $0$. I wonder if what I said is correct, and mostly I'd like to know if the sum that I found for the first integral must be calculated in some way. Thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure if this helps but it seems like that $$f=\sum_{n\ge 1}\sigma(n)e^{-nz}$$ where $\sigma(n)$ counts the number of distinct ways $n$ can be written as a product of two natural numbers.

Comment: I don't think I'm supposed to use this fact (in my course). Anyway, should I use it to calculate the sum?